# Is there a way of keeping database data in PHP while server is running?

Tags: php, html, object, tree

I'm making a website that (essentially) lets the user submit a word, matches it against a MySQL database, and returns the closest match found. My current implementation is that whenever the user submits a word, the PHP script is called, it reads the database information, scans each word one-by-one until a match is found, and returns it.

I feel like this is very inefficient. I'm about to make a program that stores the list of words in a tree structure for much more effective searching. If there are tens of thousands of words in the database, I can see the current implementation slowing down quite a bit.

My question is this: instead of having to write another, separate program, and use PHP to just connect to it with every query, can I instead save an entire data tree in memory with just PHP? That way, any session, any query would just read from memory instead of re-reading the database and rebuilding the tree over and over.

Comment: May want to look at http://memcached.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd look into running an instance of memcached on your server.  http://www.memcached.org.

You should be able to store the compiled tree of data in memory there and retrieve it for use in PHP.  You'll have to load it into PHP to perform your search, though, as well as architect a way for the tree in memcached to be updated when the database changes (assuming the word list can be updated, since there's not a good reason to store it in a database otherwise).

Comment: Thank you. I looked into the library and seems like a much easier solution than my original idea of making an entire program from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest looking at the memory table type in mysql: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html

You can then still use mysql's searching features on fast "in memory" data.

Answer (score 0):

PHP really isn't a good language for large memory structures. It's just not very memory efficient and it has a persistence problem, as you are asking about. Typically with PHP, people would store the data in some external persistent data store that is optimized for quick retrieval.

Usually people use a two fold approach:

1) Store data in the database as optimized as possible for standard queries

2) Cache results of expensive queries in memcached

If you are dealing with a lot of data that cannot be indexed easily by relational databases, then you'd probably need to roll your own daemon (e.g., written in C) that kept a persistent copy of the data structure in memory for fast querying capabilities.